# Windows Phone 8 : Web Browser - Splash Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to do little applications in windows phone 8 platform.

I'm trying to use web browser and splash screen together.

I made splash screen before application starts. But i want that splash screen has to be gone when web browser component completes loading mobile website.

I made application with googling internet but it uses sleep for a specific time. For example; "waiting 10 seconds before application starts"
Here is its code ;

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Popup _popup;
    private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker;

    public MainPage()
    {
        ShowPopup();
        InitializeComponent();
        Browser.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(BrowserNavigated);
        Browser.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(BrowserNavigating);
        Browser.ScriptNotify += new EventHandler<NotifyEventArgs>(BrowserScriptNotify);
    }

    private void ShowPopup()
    {
        _popup = new Popup();
        _popup.Child = new PopupSplash();
        _popup.IsOpen = true;

        StartLoadingData();
    }

    private void StartLoadingData()
    {
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);

        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted);
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //data loading
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    void BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this._popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
        );
    }

    void BrowserScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri(e.Value, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void BrowserNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    void BrowserNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

But my question is, how can i make " when web browser component finishes loading mobile website and make splash screen gone according that loading."

Is there any example for it ?

I need help please, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

in your xaml have a WebBrowser control with an image above it and handle the event for Load Completed.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <phone:WebBrowser LoadCompleted="WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted">

    </phone:WebBrowser>
    <Image x:Name="CoverImage" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Source="Assets\AlignmentGrid.png"></Image>

</Grid>
```

in your code behind set the visibility of the covering image to be hidden.

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.CoverImage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code for closing the popup in BrowserNavigated eventhandler.
If you mean that you want it to close when page is rendered (it's not white), then I have fought an hard battle once to resolve this problem unfortunately the WebBrowser won and I was never able to do that